# Argument-dependent PRNG

Tags: algorithm, math, random, prng

I am interested in a function `rand(x, y, seed)` that returns (pseudo) random numbers based on its arguments, with the following properties:

1. The value returned should depend on its 3 arguments, and **not** depend on the amount of times `rand` was called so far. For example, assuming these calls, in this order:

   > ```
   > rand(0, 0, 123) = 1
   > rand(0, 1, 123) = 2
   > rand(0, 2, 123) = 3
   > ```

   Then calling `rand` with the same arguments, but in a different order, we should get the same values. For example:

   > ```
   > rand(0, 1, 123) = 2
   > rand(0, 2, 123) = 3
   > rand(0, 0, 123) = 1
   > ```
2. The function should have the usual properties of a good (decent, I don't really need anything very fancy) PRNG: large period, uniform distribution etc. Returning positive integers that fit in a signed int is fine. It can also go higher if you want.
3. Assume these numbers will be used to generate a matrix. Then changing the seed should ensure that the generated matrix looks as differently as possible from matrices generated by other seeds. This should happen for as large a number of seeds as possible: I don't want matrices to repeat.

If it helps, my seeds will always be the unix timestamp in milliseconds (can be in seconds too if that makes it easier somehow). All arguments can go as high as 32 bit signed ints, but working with 64 bit values inside the function is not a problem.

What function could I use for this?

**What I thought of:**

[Perlin noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) seems to do some of what I want, but I have no idea how suitable it really is as a PRNG, especially distribution-wise. I'm also not sure how efficient it is, since my `(x, y)` parameters will be rather random, and I cannot precompute it for all of them.

I also looked into the following function:

```
p = 1400328593
rand(x, y, seed) = (x * x * seed + y * seed * seed + seed * x * y + seed) mod p
                 = (seed * (x * x + y * seed + x * y + 1)) mod p
```

This **seems** to generate good-enough numbers. Based on my (very weak) tests, they also seem to be distributed very well. Testing the period is harder though, I haven't done that.

**Update:**

Here is the output of [Ent](http://fourmilab.ch/random/) for the above function, with `time(NULL)` in C as its seed and values generated for `(x, y) in {0 ... 999} x {0 ... 999}`:

> Entropy = 3.312850 bits per byte.
>
> Optimum compression would reduce the size of this 9207076 byte file by
>   58 percent.
>
> Chi square distribution for 9207076 samples is 229710872.43, and
>   randomly would exceed this value less than 0.01 percent of the times.
>
> Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 52.3354 (127.5 = random). Monte
>   Carlo value for Pi is 4.000000000 (error 27.32 percent). Serial
>   correlation coefficient is 0.036131 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).

Is this good enough in practice (in theory, the above tests suggest that it's not good at all), or is there something well-known that I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a hash function. Pick a secure one such as SHA1 if it's not too inefficient, since it's guaranteed to have good distribution characteristics; otherwise, you can use a common hash function such as FNV. Simply use your seed and coordinates as the input data, and the hash as the random value.

Comment: Do I simply concat the three values and hash the resulting string, or is there a better way to use FNV (SHA1 is too much for my purposes). Assuming I use 64 bit FNV, do you know how well this will behave in practice, assuming I might be populating really large matrices with it? Like, will areas repeat, will I get repeated matrices with different seeds often etc.? The tests I linked to in my OP all rate this, Running Wild's, C's rand() and my function the same: very bad. I'm thinking the tests are either bad or too demanding for what I need, but I figure I'd ask if you know more just in case.

Comment: @IVlad Concatenate them in some fashion that's unambiguous, by using fixed length fields or delimiters. How you do it isn't important as long as it's consistent and unambiguous. FNV is fairly good, but I can't guarantee its performance - I'd suggest trying it out yourself. There are many other fairly simple hash functions you can try if that one doesn't measure up.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub).  It has the property that you can compute the n'th value of the series directly, which seems appropriate for your situation.  It takes three parameters, p, q, and x0.  p and q are prime and x0 is relateively prime to both p and q.  So your arguments x and y could be used to find the x'th and y'th primes, then they would be suitable for p and q, and then you could use your third parameter to find a suitable value for x0.  This is a bit tedious, and Blum Blum Shub is slow since it is a cryptographic RNG, but if you don't really require speed then it would work and wouldn't be terribly difficult to implement.

Another way to do this would be to take a RNG like [CMWC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry#Complementary-multiply-with-carry_generators) and fill the i'th position of the generator with something like x + y^i + seed^(2i), run the generator for a little while (maybe a number of times equal to the number of values it stores), then pull a value out of it.

If you want to use a CMWC you can look at an implementation I have on github [here](https://github.com/runningwild/cmwc), and values for constructing the generator with known periods [here](https://github.com/runningwild/cmwc/blob/master/rand.go).

Comment: That would be too slow I think - I don't need it to be as fast as possible, but Blum Blum sounds too slow. My `(x, y)` are also rather random and can be very high, so I cannot precompute them like you suggest in CMWC (if I understood correctly).

Comment: The (x, y, seed) is just used to seed the RNG, they can be any values at all.  A CMWC is created from known values, but these are independent of your (x, y, seed) values.

Comment: I don't really get it, could you provide an example please? I need the output of each call to depend on `(x, y)` too. Plus, wouldn't this break my call-order requirement? I need call order not to matter as long as the `x` and `y` are the same.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/QkjUlQq4HS
This uses the CMWC implementation I have and sets the three values in the generator to the values supplied by (x, y, seed).  Out of curiosity, why do you need to be able to call these values out of order?  If you are going to fill a matrix in why not just choose seed and then always fill the matrix in the same order?

Comment: I don't fully understand that language, but I think I get your suggestion now. You mean I should reseed the CMWC implementation with `(x, y, seed)` for each `(x, y)`, correct? Do you know how this would affect its properties, or if it would be better than simply reseeding java's random function with something like `x * y * seed` or other function of `x, y, seed`? I need to be able to get the values out of order because this will be a game where a random number is generated when the player clicks on a cell. Boards can also be saved and exchanged between players, and I need them to match.

Comment: Also, in your example formula, by `^` do you mean `xor` as in Wikipedia, or power of?

Comment: Correct, you should reseed for each (x, y).

It would be better than reseeding java's rng because (I'm assuming) the seed function takes a single integer, whereas in this case the state of the rng is three integers, which is exactly what you want to use to seed it.  The difference may be negligible, though, depending on how good an rng you really want.

^ means xor.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. +1, I will run some tests with this and get back to you. I'll accept it in a couple of days if no one suggests anything better.

Comment: @IVlad You mentioned in other comments that this RNG does not do well against your tests, but when I run output of this generator (with the parameters I suggested to you) ent tells me Entropy = 7.999735 bits per byte, which is pretty darned good.  Can you tell me what you saw that made you think this was not a good solution?

Comment: Hmm, I must be doing something wrong then. I see entropy around 3.3 for all solutions posted. Could you post your implementation and how you tested it please?

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/0UzVrJLBze.  This won't do anything if you run it in the playground, but I ran exactly that code, which should simulate generating a 100x100 matrix.  ent says "Entropy = 7.995454 bits per byte."  for the file generated by this exact program.

Comment: Also just realized that earlier I was wrong, I mean to say that a^b refers to a to the b'th power in my earlier sample equation.

Comment: You were right, I was running the tests wrong. However, with Nick's suggestion - a FNV64 hash - the entropy is constantly around `7.999962`, and it's doing better in the other tests too. I will be going with that for now, but thanks a lot for your time and suggestion.